How to I select an 80/10/10 split when using Databricks AutoML
Headline says it all. I am doing a regression and want to select a test, validation, and train split that is not 60/20/20. Anyone know how to do this?
I looked into the documentation and wonder if that feature is just not there. I

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
